# react map array of objects separately

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have facing an issue in React JS. I want to show full name data separately.

Array of Object

```
0: {id: "1", wp_user_id: null, facebook_id: null, group_id: null, full_name: "furqan", …}
1: {id: "3", wp_user_id: null, facebook_id: null, group_id: null, full_name: "hassan",..}
```

My Code:

```
   this.state = {
        cusomterdata:[],      
      }
    }

    render() {  
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.cusomterdata.map(function(item, i){
              return ([
                        <p key={i}>{item.full_name}</p>,
                        <p key={i}>{item.id}</p>,
                    ]);
                })}
            <div>
        )
    }
```

When i run this code Result here, They both come together

```
 - furqan
 - 1
 - hassan
 - 3
```

I want to do like this but it is not working.

```
     <p key={i}>{item.full_name[0]}</p>,   //just show first fullname
```

**Expected Output**
[image]

What should i do? Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the expected output in view?

Comment: added screenshot you can check it. [@Ashish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4976422/ashish-ranjan)

Comment: @MHasan The screenshot woudn't make sense, just as you have mentioned *When i run this code Result here, They both come together(and then the description)*, please also mention how you expect it be.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'full_name' of undefined [@Ajeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2873538/ajeet-shah)

Comment: sorry my mistake i should update the expected output  [@Ashish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4976422/ashish-ranjan)

Comment: did you understand the problem ? [@Ashish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4976422/ashish-ranjan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have understood, you just want to show the full_name only from the first item.

You may do the following:

```
render() {

    let FullName = null;
    if (this.state.cusomterdata) {
        FullName = (
            {
                this.state.cusomterdata.map((data, index) => {
                    return (
                        <p key={index}>{data.full_name}</p>
                    )
                })
            }
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            { FullName }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro [@Ashish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4976422/ashish-ranjan)

Comment: can you do it `index` dynamically? if a have multiple fullname in arrays ? please [@Ashish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4976422/ashish-ranjan)

Comment: @MHasan Okay, do you  mean that you don't want ids to be displayed, but just the fullname of all the elements of the Array?

Comment: yes you right just display all `fullname` [@Ashish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4976422/ashish-ranjan)

Comment: @MHasan Probably the updated answer should work for you, you could also had done the same thing, just by removing the `<p key={i}>{item.id}</p>,` part and probably not returning an array from the map.

Comment: ok thank for your time [@Ashish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4976422/ashish-ranjan)